# So the * for function pointer can be omitted?

Tags: c, function-pointers, shorthand

`gcc`seems to be telling me `int foo(int (*f)(void))` is the same as `int foo(int (f)(void))`
`f` is a pointer to a function taking no argument returning `int`. Why can we omit the `*` here.

However, I also tried `int (*p)(void)` and `int (p)(void)`. The first `p` is a function pointer, while the second is a function.

So, what's happening? Under what circumstances can the asterisk be omitted?
I look it up in K&R and discovered nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote from my copy of Harbison and Steele (5th edition, section 9.3):

> In parameter lists, a type "function returning T" is implicitly rewritten to have type "pointer to function returning T".

That means that in the context of a formal parameter list, they are equivalent. In any other context, they are different.

As a matter of style, I would never omit the *.

Comment: Thanks. And I also know when calling the pointed function `(*f)()` is the same as `f()`.

Comment: @TheoYou: Yes, due to a separate rule regarding implicit conversions of expressions of function type. Even in a regular function call `func(arg)`, the expression `func` is implicitly converted to a pointer, which is what the `()` function call "operator" requires. Similar things happen for arrays, both in parameter declarations and in expressions.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks. This kind of implicit conversions explains many special cases.